# SSH server is enabled on Windows 10 pro by default

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssh, security

I was doing some tests and was surprised to find that I could open an SSH session to my Windows 10 pro PC.

I did not enable SSH server and I'm pretty sure it was not open before. Even When I blocked the SSH port using Windows firewall and my 3rd party firewall software, SSH was still open. I finally found the two services "SshBroker" and "SshProxy" running so I disabled them and SSH was closed. The services startup type was set to manual.

Did Microsoft release an update recently that runs those services by default or should I be concerned?

**UPDATE:** I suddenly found the services running again although startup type is manual. The PC was updated and restarted a few times before I noticed.

Comment: Interesting... MS *did* include OpenSSH in v. 1709, Fall Creatos' update; this feature had been in Beta previously. It is not supposed to be enabled by default, though, but perhaps the test procedure turned it on. See https://poweruser.blog/enabling-the-hidden-openssh-server-in-windows-10-fall-creators-update-1709-and-why-its-great-51c9d06db8df

Comment: I can promise you that the beta SSH feature is NOT enabled by default.  Windows has two SSH features, one that must be enabled and is based on OpenSSH, and one built-into PowerShell.  Which feature do you believe is enabled by default?

Comment: @Ramhound Please note that I'm talking about an SSH server (allows access to my system remotely), not the SSH client in PowerShell. That being said, I believe it's NOT the OpenSSH server mentioned in DrMoishe Pippik's article above. It's the one built in the system. I hope the name of the services mentioned in my question would make it clear.

Comment: Do you have Developer mode enabled?

Comment: @grawity yes it is.